# Stored procedure update column SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Tengo un problema que no he logrado solucionar: Tengo una tabla llamada `MisVentas`, la cual contiene mas de 10 columnas de X nombre.

Necesito hacer un *SP* que se encargue de actualizar esa tabla en forma dinámica. Me explico:

Este *SP* lo debe consumir una *API* que a su vez recibirá la información —los campos y sus valores— desde un cliente. Debe recibir como parámetro el campo que necesito actualizar junto con su valor; puede recibir 1 o mas campos junto con sus respectivos valores.

Esto es para evitar tener que hacer un procedimiento por columna a actualizar de mi tabla.

Quedo atento a vuestros comentarios.

Comment: Crea un procedimiento que actualice todas las columnas. Si el valor no cambia, solo actualiza la columna con su propio valor.

Comment: La API conoce el listado de campos a actuliazar ?

Comment: ¿Por qué utilizar un _SP_ en este caso?. Creo que podría ser más simple y óptimo construir dinamicamente la sentencia `update` dentro del lenguaje de programación del API y lanzar esa sentencia contra la base de datos. ¿Has explorado esa solución?

Comment: ¿Te refieres a actualizar los nombres y tipo de dato de las columnas?

Comment: @jachguate te esta comentando exactamente lo mismo que te comente en el chat... Yo tampoco entendi el sentido de esto. es mas, genera muchisimos problemas con los tipos de datos

Comment: Ya encontré una solución optima. Enviar un modelo de datos completo (la tabla) al SP para que actualice el modelo de datos completo. Disculpen si no me supe explicar bien.

Answer (score -1):

Lo resolví de esta forma:

```
    /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GetBillCustomer]    Script Date: 03-06-2019 12:45:08 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author, , Name>
-- Create Date: <Create Date, , >
-- Description: <Description, , >
-- =============================================

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateSale]

@ParamID INT,
@Param2 INT,
@Param2 DATETIME,
@Param3 NVARCHAR(MAX)
@Param4 INT

AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

UPDATE MiVenta
SET 
    [NombreColumna1] = @Param1 ,
    [NombreColumna2] = @Param2 ,
    [NombreColumna3] = @Param3 ,
    [NombreColumna4] = @Param4 
WHERE [NombreColumnaID] = @ParamID
```

Comment: Recuerdo que tu tabla tenía más de 10 columnas. ¿Estás pasando los más de 10 parámetros cada vez? ¿qué pasa si solamente quieres actualizar uno de los campos?

Comment: Hay varias deficiencias en esto, por ejemplo, si más adelante, si quieres identificar en un _trigger_ si se está actualizando una columna, vas a tener que desarrollar una lógica más completa, pues el campo siempre va a estar incluido en la clausula `update`, aunque el usuario no pretenda modificarlo.

Comment: @jachguate Si contiene mas de 10 columnas, pero solo coloque algunas en forma de ejemplo. Contestando la pregunta, se actualizarían todos los datos. Usando la lógica de un objeto que pasa si tengo un auto (objeto) y lo quiero modificar, debo traerme el auto (objeto) para poder modificarlo (si esta mal esto, cual seria la forma correcta?)

Comment: No se si es correcto o no, pero lo que pasa es que **tu respuesta no responde a tu pregunta**. En la pregunta dices: _"Debe recibir como parámetro el campo que necesito actualizar junto con su valor; puede recibir 1 o mas campos junto con sus respectivos valores"_, Tu respuesta, sin embargo, requiere que se pasen siempre todos los campos.